# How can I convert an object to float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, type-conversion

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyW3S.png)
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1v6c.png)

I tried making a boxplot for 'horsepower', but it shows up as an object type, so I tried converting it to float but it displays that error.

Answer (score 0):

The column `horsepower` seems to hold some non numeric values. I suggest you, in this case, to use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) instead of [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

Replace this :

```
df_T['horsepower']= df_T['horsepower'].astype(float)
```

By this :

```
df_T['horsepower']= pd.to_numeric(df_T['horsepower'], errors= 'coerce')
```

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.

Comment: df_T['horsepower']= pd.to_numeric(df_T['horsepower'], errors= 'coerce')

missed a ']' near horsepower

Comment: Updated, thanks Tron ;)